# Salesforce Magento integration

Tags: rest-api, magento-2.2.5, oauth

I'm implementing salesforce magento integration through REST API callout. I have successfully got the response from magento and saved it in salesforce database. But facing issue while using filterCriteria in the query, it throws me "Invalid Signature". please help me solve this error.

Thanks in advance....!